# Unable to access object properties from URL params in Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, json, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to access object properties from a request from my Angular app. I am using Laravel 5.1

Angular:

```
console.log('getQuestionAnswers', params);
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url + ver + '/questions/checkMany',
    params: {
        'questions[]' : params
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + $rootScope.access_token
    },
    cache: true
});
```

Console.log of params:

[image]

Laravel:

```
public function getAnswers(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $question_objs = $input['questions'];

    foreach ($question_objs as $question_answer_object) {
        return $question_answer_object;
```

Response to Angular with: `return $question_objs;`

[image]

Response to Angular with: `return $question_answer_object;`

[image]

Looks like so far so good!

---

But if I try to access a property within laravel, like question_id:

`return $question_answer_object['question_id'];`

I get error:

> "Illegal string offset 'question_id'

Laravel already parses the JSON,

```
    // From Illuminate/Http/Request.php all() method:

    if (! isset($this->json)) {
        $this->json = new ParameterBag((array) json_decode($this->getContent(), true));
    }
```

and when I return it, I can see it's an object. Why can't I access the properties? I've also tried `json_decode` without luck.

---

With JSON Decode:

```
$test = json_decode($question_answer_object, true);
return $test['question_id'];
```

This seems to work. But why?

---

Accessing the property on the object as such:

```
return $question_answer_object->question_id;
```

Gives the following error:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud plz see above attempt with json decode

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud okay it worked. But I thought Laravel's `$request->all()` does `return array_replace_recursive($this->input(), $this->files->all());` and recursively `json_decodes`? Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$question_answer_object['question_id']` variable is a string comprising JSON encoded data; to access that, you need to decode it first:

```
$decoded= json_decode($question_answer_object['question_id'], true);
return $decoded['question_id'];
```

If you're not sending the request as application/json, use `$request->json()`.
You can get some information about this issues **[here](http://laravel.io/forum/07-29-2014-help-with-responsejson-to-json-decode).**

Answer (score 0):

Returned question is an object, not an array. You have to acces it with `->`

```
return $question_answer_object->question_id;
```

Comment: I can't access a property on an object with `obj['key']`?

Comment: Not unless the object implements `ArrayAccess` interface which `stdClass` returned by `json_decode` does not.

Comment: Please see above edit. I get `"Trying to get property of non-object"`

Comment: And if this was the case, Why does this work: `$question_objs = $input['questions'];` As $input[questions] is a key